# How much strength progress can I expect on a cut if I'm fat? Is it even required given that I don't want to get more fat?

Tags: muscle, strength, stronglifts, cutting

Please help an early novice here!

I'm fat (28%bf, 170lbs, 5'6'') and am following stronglifts 5x5 with some arm, forearm work. S:B:D is 143:95:225. I'm planning to cut down to 140lbs so I can lean bulk over 1-2 years to 150ish.
So during my cut how much gains can I really expect? (My S:B:D some months ago was 200:170:270). **Should I even cut that much weight?** Please guide me.

**Goals are**: To get lean and stronger OR to milk out as much novice linear progression goals as possible and reducing as much fat as I possibly can or wosrst case: staying at the same body fat.

Comment: Did your SBD drop from lack of training?

Comment: @DeeV it did not really drop, it's that stronglifts 5x5 insists that you start with 40-50% of your previous load capacity so that you dont stall soon and you can make progress for a long time. These are my exercise numbers, not my max effort 5RMs currently

Comment: For someone at 28% bf it sounds reasonable to go down to 12-15%bf before bulking. You'll gain some fat in the process anyway, might as well make it easier to cut again to the same point at the end of the bulk.